# how to put all the templates in a single file and access them in jinja2 from python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, templates, jinja2

I have 30 to 40 SQL queries and I want to use jinja2 template files for storing the queries so that the python code and SQL queries are stored separately

for each SQL query, I am creating a separate template file and loading that template using the python code given below

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
    
def main():
    file_loader = FileSystemLoader('path to templates')

    template_group = Environment(loader=file_loader)

    select_template = template_group.get_template("select_query.txt")

    print(select_template.render())
```

the content of select_query.txt is

```
select * from employee.details where department="cse"
```

this is fine for just 3 queries which take 3 separate template files, but I have 30 to 40 queries and they may increase in the future,

Is there any way to put all the SQL queries in a single template file and access those queries from the python code

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think thats what the `urls.py` is for

Comment: @EgonStetmann. Please can you point me to the resources for urls.py

Comment: i just couldnt imagine someone using jinja without django sorry https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/

Comment: I explored the best practices for storing the SQL queries but couldn't decide on that and my team members suggested me to use jinja2  and I eventually landed into thinking about the solution for the above question

Comment: well with django you use models and the automatic generated queries save on the `migrations` folders of each app of your project

Answer (score 0):

You should create the file where you will store the templates as a .py file, not txt, because you want to import it to your application file.
Then you can create a variable that will store a basic SQL template. This SQL template can have placeholders, so you can condense similar queries into a single one. For example:

```py
sum_emails_by_event = """
SELECT
    date_,
    {%- for event in events %}
    SUM(CASE WHEN event_type = '{{event}}' THEN 1 END) AS num_{{event}}
    {%- if not loop.last -%}
        , 
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor %}
FROM raw_events
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC
"""

print(Template(sum_emails_by_event).render(events=['send', 'deliver', 'open', 'click']))
```

This code will loop through the events list and create SUM statements for each of the items of the events list. If you just stored them in a txt file, you would have to store a huge number of different variations of this query.